# Can Django Cache Handle Any Variable Type

Tags: django, django-cache

I am hoping to use Django's Caching functionality, more specifically Memcached to store Zip objects which are created by joining two lists.

For example:

```
# Two lists
names = ['peter', 'paul', 'mary']
jobs = ['teacher, 'music man', 'chef']

# Combine them to form Zip object
combined = zip(names, jobs)

# Can be accessed like so:
for name, job in combined:
    print(name, job)
```

I am asking, because I currently am trying to cache the zip object but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: There is no special `zip` object; it is simply a `list` of `list`s and can be cached.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the response. That prob means I'm messing up something then. I'm a bit of a noob at caching, would you mind taking a look at [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711283/caching-zip-object-with-django-memcached) to see if you can spot the issue.